# Controlling fan speed with Windows without additional programs

Tags: windows-10, fan, asus-laptop, speedfan

This is clearly a duplicate of at least five question with almost the same title of mine. However I tried all the free programs in the respective answers and none of them worked for me. For this reason I chosen to ask a new question.

This is my motherboard (result from `wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version`)

```
Manufacturer           Product  Version
ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.  X550VX   1.0
```

This is my current up to date BIOS (result from `wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion`)

```
SMBIOSBIOSVersion
X550VX.302
```

Obviously I didn't found any field to control my fan.

When I'm on linux I have no problem, the fan speed is enough to keep my CPU cool enough. In Windows 10 the fan speed is ~3100rpm at 65°C and 3% of usage and is ~3400rpm at 100°C and 50% of usage or more.

My wish is to find a solution using the control panel, the prompt or some configuration file but if anything like that is possible even a tool is well accepted. Until now I din't found any tool, script, configuration, instruction and so on that works for me.

**Edit:**
I realized that I didn't specified that on linux the fan speed is enough to keep my CPU cool enough because is higher than 3400rpm even at 45°C.

Comment: What temps is your CPU reaching in Windows under low and high loads? Is the system overheating when running Windows? Is something actually broken?

Comment: Have you checked for and installed any updated BIOS or other system firmware and drivers?

Comment: Also, the other tools are generally recommended because they work well. Are you getting errors when you try to run one of the other suggested utilities such as SpeedFan? Is the system behaving incorrectly when using these other utilities?

Comment: @music2myear I wrote those informations: when cpu is around 3% is something like 65°C and with a load of 50% or more touch 100°C (then thermal throttling activates and remains at 100°C even if the load is more). These infos are under windows.

Comment: @music2myear I also wrote that my bios is up to date (06/2017). Idem for all common asus drivers. (even if there isn't any specifical for fan control)

Comment: I tried to use other tools but my mother board (x550vx) isn't supported. With speedfun I'm able to check the velocity of my fan but nothing more. Specifically nothing happens using that utility.

Comment: Did you try using the RWEeverything utility mentioned by others who said SpeedFan doesn't work?